# Long display name push mod links out

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

`.additional-links` is pushed out from the left of display name.

[image]

This display name box has `max-width: 400px`, but it's too wide for mods with more tabs and menus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a mod access a user profile with a long display name, the max width has been set to 150px, which should be enough to not drop the mod items down.

In these cases, a tooltip with the full display name will be set on the truncated display name.