# Long usernames skew "Others with this badge" list item alignment

Tags: bug, design, badges, display-names

On the "Others with this badge" page [(this one is a good example)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/populist), if one of the users who gained the related badge has a rather long username, their profile's alignment will be pushed over to the left instead of being correctly aligned to the right.

Screenshots:

[image: Profile alignment 1]

[image: Profile alignment 2]

This doesn't appear to be intentional. Could this be fixed?

---

Oh, and because [there's a contest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349555/622284) going on, here's a [Haiku Sonnet](https://www.writersdigest.com/write-better-poetry/haiku-sonnet-poetic-form), a combination of two poetic forms that shouldn't really go together. I found it rather fitting because long usernames and the "Others with this badge" list don't really go together.

> "Others with this badge,"
> Has issues with its spacing
> And its alignment

> With names, long displayed,
> The list item appears wrong,
> And might need some work

> With names like Shog9,
> There's not a visual bug,
> And it renders fine

> But, others are long
> Shadow Wizard Wearing Mask
> Throws alignment off

> Could this please be looked into,
> Perhaps tagged [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)?

Comment: Somewhat similar, and not particularly old: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303408/282094 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317193/character-overflow-on-profile-page-with-long-usernames?rq=1 - those have not been fixed; I found a few other similar ones over a half dozen years old marked status-completed (but the layout certainly has changed since then).